# Is this C implementation of Fisher-Yates shuffle correct?

Tags: c, shuffle

Here's a C implementation of Fisher-Yates that I want to use in a deck-shuffling routine. Am I doing this correctly (n = length of array)?

Note: The do-while loop attempts to correct for the modulo bias (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modulo_bias)). It adds a bit of overhead to the procedure and could be eliminated if you don't care about the low-bit bias.

```
void shuffle(int *array, int n) {

  int i, j, tmp, upper_bound;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {

    upper_bound = RAND_MAX - ((RAND_MAX % (i + 1)) + 1);

    do {
      j = rand() % (i + 1);
    } while (j > upper_bound);

    tmp = array[j];
    array[j] = array[i];
    array[i] = tmp;   
  }
}
```

Comment: It just popped into my head that `int lim = RAND_MAX-i;` ... `} while (j>upper_bound && --lim);` might be a suitable way to catch the _it_  _can_  _never_  _happen_ case of repeated out of range random numbers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, you should extract the code for generating a random number that's equally distributed between `0` (inclusive) and `n` (exclusive) to a separate function. That's a nice task of work that you will need elsewhere, too.

Second, I would not call `srand` inside the `shuffle` function but depend on the caller on initializing the random number generator. That way you can shuffle a deck more than once in a second.

Third, you should do the test for `j > upper_bound` before dividing by `i + 1`. It's unlikely that `i` will ever be near `RAND_MAX`.

```
static int rand_int(int n) {
  int limit = RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX % n;
  int rnd;

  do {
    rnd = rand();
  } while (rnd >= limit);
  return rnd % n;
}

void shuffle(int *array, int n) {
  int i, j, tmp;

  for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = rand_int(i + 1);
    tmp = array[j];
    array[j] = array[i];
    array[i] = tmp;
  }
}
```

To check whether this implementation may be correct, you need to ensure that you asked the random number generator for `log2(n!)` bits of randomness. In other words, the product of all the `n`s given to the `rand_int` function must be `n!`.

Comment: +1 for the comment on seeding.  It's also a "security" issue if external users of your code can predict/influence your shuffle by controlling timing.

Comment: What does it mean to have the caller initialize the random number? Is that like depending on the caller's mouse movements or something?

Comment: No. What it means is: Any experienced programmer would not expect a routine called `shuffle` to reset the random number generator to a specific state. That's just not included in the word `shuffle`. The only point where you should call `srand()` is in the `main` function. As a guide, just ask yourself: "What does this function do?" The answer for the `shuffle` function would be: "It shuffles the given array *and resets the random number generator*." This alone should sound weird enough.

Comment: Eliminate need for 'tmp' by using std::swap in <algorithm>:

    ...
    j = rand_int(i+1);
    std::swap(array[i],array[j]);

Comment: @KomodoDave This would save you a single unit of memory, but at the expense of the overhead and context switching involved in calling the `swap` function. Also, this appears to be pure C, not C++, so it likely isn't an option anyways.

Comment: Note that to isolate this code from other random number generation, you might want to look into using `nrand48()`, and provide one method to set a random seed and another to generate a random seed automatically from `/dev/urandom` or something similar.  This allows you to decouple the shuffling from any other random number generation in the program (but beware `lcong48()`).