# Fast way to avoid modulo bias

Tags: c++

I'm doing a shuffle and it gets done very often on a small array.  Could be anything from 1 - 10 elements.

I've tried the accepted answer in this question:

[Is this C implementation of Fisher-Yates shuffle correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343797/is-this-c-implementation-of-fisher-yates-shuffle-correct)

Unfortunately it's extremely slow.

I need a faster way of doing this and avoiding modulo bias which I'm seeing.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Sorry I should point out that it's not the shuffle that's slow, it's the method used to generate a random int range. i.e. rand_int().   I'm using a Mersenne twister algorithm and RAND_MAX in my case is UINT_MAX to help out.  This of course makes it slower when n is much smaller than RAND_MAX

I've also found 2 implementations of a rand_int type function.

```
static int rand_int(int n) {
  int limit = RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX % n;
  int rnd;

  do {
    rnd = rand();
  } while (rnd >= limit);
  return rnd % n;
}
```

The following is much much faster.  But, does it avoid the modulo bias problem?

```
int rand_int(int limit) {

    int divisor = RAND_MAX/(limit);
    int retval;

    do { 
        retval = rand() / divisor;
    } while (retval > limit);

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: In what way is it slow? It only does N swaps, after all.

Comment: How random does the shuffle have to be?  You could pre-generate a bunch of shuffles for your average array sizes, store them in a look-up table, and then simply iterate through those randomized indices.  Expand the number of pre-generated LUT entries to whatever memory envelope and make sure the number of entries is a power of 2 for cheap modulo operations on the LUT indices.  The LUT array would be lut[small array size][0..2**n] -> "random" array indices

Comment: could you describe how the modulo bias appears, what exactly you're getting?

Comment: Alf. it was simply that some values were appearing too often in the output.  Usually in the bottom end. I'm not getting this after implementing some changes from sehe's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

To address the basic question on avoiding the modulo bias with `rand()` see http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx.

In short, you can't get truly uniform other than skipping non-domain random numbers<sup>1</sup>; The article lists some formulae to get a smaller bias (`int r = rand() / ( RAND_MAX / N + 1 )` eg) without sacrificing more performance.

<sup>1</sup> See Java's implementation of Random.nextInt(int): 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

---

#### Using C++

You should be able to use [`std::random_shuffle`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/random_shuffle.html) (from `<algorithm>` header);

If you must roll your own shuffle implementation, I suggest using std::random (TR1, C++0x or Boost). It comes with a number of generators and distributions, with varying performance characteristics.

```
#include <random>

std::mt19937 rng(seed);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> gen(0, N); // uniform, unbiased

int r = gen(rng);
```

Refer to the boost documentation for a good overview of Boost Random generator and distribution characteristics:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.generators

Here is a sample of doing `std::random_shuffle` using Boost Random, directly:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

struct Rng
{
    Rng(boost::mt19937 &rng) : _rng(rng) {}

    unsigned operator()(unsigned i) 
    {
        boost::uniform_int<> dist(0, i - 1);
        return dist(_rng);
    }

  private:        
    boost::mt19937 &_rng;
};

boost::mt19937 state;
std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), Rng(state));
```

Comment: Sorry I can't use boost or C++0X.

Comment: @MattH: so that leaves TR1 as an option. std::mt19937 is in TR1 too

Comment: @MattH: Edited answer with more info regarding modulo bias with `rand`

Comment: @MattH: also, on the topic of `std::random_shuffle`, what is your verdict? It has been in STL ever since SGI...

Comment: thanks.  Didn't know about std::random_shuffle. I had implemented my own, partly because the boss doesn't like me using the std library too much but rather an internal library.  I'm changing my mind about that.

Comment: Thanks, that first link is priceless!.

Comment: As of 2019-04-30 16:30 -07:00, the first link has a 500 error (internal server error).  However, you can find the article in the Wayback Machine (Internet Archive) up to 2018-08-01: https://web.archive.org/web/20180801210127/http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx