# Consecutive numbers in random order

Tags: c++

How to generate an array which contains a group of consecutive numbers but with random order? For example, the consecutive numbers are from 8 to 100 (no duplicates), and what I want is an array containing all of these numbers but the sequence is random.

Comment: Sounds almost like shuffling a deck of cards.

Comment: Use `std::random_shuffle`, take a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948091/how-to-generate-an-array-of-256-distinct-numbers/21948500#21948500

Comment: Why don't you guys post your comment as answer, rather than as comment?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that 8 and 100 are included in the range.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
   const size_t N = 93;
   int a[N];

   std::iota( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), 8 );
   std::random_shuffle( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );
}
```

If 8 is a typo in your post and you meant 0 then the code will look as

```
   const size_t N = 101;
   int a[N];

   std::iota( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), 0 );
```

Comment: What's `std::itoa`?  I can't find it in my copy of the standard (and the parameters you pass it don't look like those for the function of this name in older Unices).

Comment: @lisyarus I misread it; I read `itoa` (which was present in all of the early Unices, but didn't make it into any standard).  That's also what I searched for in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are student and new to programming therefore some basics should be told.

rand() generates random number.

If you want the number to be in a particular range then take its mod e.g.

```
rand()%93;    // generate random numbers from 0-92
```

Similarly,
    (rand()%93)+8 // will generate number between 8-100

Moreover, for checking duplicates you can compare the number with those which already stored in the array.

Comment: Comparing to already generated numbers can be extremely slow and it's time cost highly depends on used pseudo-random numbers generation algorithm. Generating a sequence and then shuffling it is a much better idea, since it' time cost is linear.

Comment: What if a number (lets say 0) is generated after an infinite amount of time ?