# Generating random non repeating number array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, random, dynamically-generated

I need to generate random non repeating number array in C++, in this part of code I generate random numbers using, srand function, but some of the numbers are repeating. The main task is to generate random numbers for lottery ticket, so I need to generate numbers until golden number which is marked as int golden.

> ```
> #include <cstdlib>
> #include <ctime>
> #include <iostream>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> int main()
> {
>   int golden = 31;
>   int i = 0;
>   int array[35];
>
>  srand((unsigned)time(0));
>     while(i != golden){
>         array[i] = (rand()%75)+1;
>         cout << array[i] << endl;
>         i++;
> }
>  }
> ```

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948091/how-to-generate-an-array-of-256-distinct-numbers/21950195

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842289 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538 [python using built-in] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473321 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One strategy is to populate an array with numbers from 1 to 75, and then use [`std::random_shuffle()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) on it. You can then read the numbers from the array until you hit the golden number.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task and used two functions to solve the problem of repeating numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void generateRandom(int array[], int length);
bool findVal(int array[], int size, int value);

int main() {
    int arraySize = 10;
    int array[arraySize];

    generateRandom(array, arraySize);
    for (auto i : array) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}

void generateRandom(int array[], int length) {
    srand((int) time(nullptr));
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        temp = rand() % 20 + 1;
        if (findVal(array, i, temp)) {
            i--;
            continue;
        } else {
            array[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

bool findVal(int *array, int size, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (array[i] == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Within the `generateRandom` function, you can switch the `20` and `1` used in the for loop with your preferred upper and lower limits respectively.