# How to apply Fisher-Yates to C program?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have tried a lot of things so far but havent been able to get the Fisher-Yates algorithm working as a shuffle algorithm. I'm having trouble applying it to my code.

I got the playlist to sort in alphabetical order but now I need to get it to shuffle. This is where I'm lost. Below is my code and the playlist text file. I have also attached images of the code and text file. Help would be greatly appreciated thank you. This is all done using eclipse. [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXiW1)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vYva.png).png

CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(void)

{
    int s, i;
    const char *SHUFFLE_PLAYLISTS_FILE_PATH = "./InputFiles/playlist.txt"; // location of playlist file
    char SongArr[100][100], temp[100]; // stores song data (limited to nine rows)
    int songNum = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(SHUFFLE_PLAYLISTS_FILE_PATH,  "r+" );       /* open for reading */
//   This will take each row in the file and store it in SongArr.
    if (fp == NULL )
    {      /* check does playlist file exist etc */
        perror ("Error opening playlist file");
        songNum = -1; /* use this as a file not found code */

    }
    else
    {
        // fgets returns NULL when it gets to the end of the file
        while ( fgets( SongArr[songNum], sizeof(SongArr[songNum]), fp ) != NULL )
        {
            songNum++;
        }
        fclose (fp);
    }

    for(s = 0; s <= songNum; s++)
    {
        for (i = s+1; i <= songNum; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(SongArr[s], SongArr[i])>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, SongArr[s]);
                strcpy(SongArr[s], SongArr[i]);
                strcpy(SongArr[i], temp);
            }
        }
    }
    //Prints the result of sorted songs
    printf("Order of Sorted Strings: \n");

    for(s = 0; s <= songNum; s++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", SongArr[s]);
    }

    void shuffle(int *SongArr, int n)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int temp;
        for(s = n - 1; s > 0; s--)
        {
            i = rand() % (i +1);
            temp = SongArr[i];
            SongArr[i] = SongArr[s];
            SongArr[s] = temp;
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

playlist.txt file

```
Taylor Swift     - Everything Has Changed
Mumford and Sons - Little Lion Man
Hozier           - Sedated
Mumford and Sons - Babel
Taylor Swift     - I Knew You Were Trouble
Taylor Swift     - We Are Never Ever Getting Back Together
Hozier           - Jackie and Wilson
Hozier           - Take Me To Church
Hozier           - Angel of Small Death & The Codeine Scene
```

Comment: Here is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343797/is-this-c-implementation-of-fisher-yates-shuffle-correct?rq=1.

Comment: Your `shuffle` routine needs to copy strings (`char` arrays), not integers. Your code formatting is incorrect as `shuffle` is defined inside `main`. Variable `i` is not defined in `shuffle`. `i = rand() % (i + 1);` should be `i = rand() % (s + 1);`.

Comment: ive seen that question but i do not know what is going on and how it was applied to the program thus why im asking for detailed help

Comment: thank you ian i will address those errors you have listed now :)

Comment: regarding this line: `songNum = -1;`,  Much better, at this point to call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  so the user can correct the problem.

Comment: in C, array indexing starts with 0 and continues to (number of elements in array -1).  so a statement like: array[max_elements] is accessing beyond the end of the array.  This is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.   As an example, this line: `for (i = s+1; i <= songNum; i++)` should be: `for ( i = s; i < songNum; i++ )`  and this line: `for(s = 0; s <= songNum; s++)` should be: `for(s = 0; s < songNum; s++)`