# in c,how to generate random numbers without any duplicate

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm trying to generate random numbers without any duplicate, like from 1 to 5 I want it to be 2 3 1 5 4 not 2 2 2 1 5. I've tried it but something went wrong and the code didn't work properly.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int random(int minN, int maxN){
    return minN + rand() % (maxN + 1 - minN);
}
 
int main(){
    int max,min;
    printf("nhap max ");
    scanf("%d", &max);

    printf("nhap min ");
    scanf("%d", &min);
    srand((int)time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        int arr[100];
        arr[i] = random(min,max);
        if(i!=0){
            for(int j=i-1; j>=0;j-1){
                if (arr[i]==arr[j])
                    continue;
            }
        }
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't sound random to me. You probably want the numbers from 1 to 5 in a random order, which is something quite different.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The nature of random numbers is that they can repeat. What you want instead is a given set of numbers in random order. You might put all numbers in an array and create random index to pick one number from that array and remove afterwards.

Comment: Does your compiler issue some warning about "expression without any side effect"? for your loop: `; j-1}`. Running your program in a debugger should reveal that endless loop within seconds.

Comment: Besides the previous comments, "and the code didn't work properly." is not a very useful statement. What does or does not happen incorrectly? Please read [How To ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide sample input, expected output and real output.

Comment: You want to shuffle the array `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` instead. Try [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: You are probably looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321370/fisher-yates-shuffling-algorithm-in-c

Comment: thank everyone, I'm still new with all of this so my question may be silly but thank you all for your help.

Answer (score -4):

While generating random number instead of random(min,max); you can use below:

```
int random_int(int min, int max) { return min + rand() % (max+1 - min);}
```

Comment: How does this address the "no duplicates" part of the question? And how is this different from the code in the question? That only uses slightly different names.