# How to use random() in C

Tags: c, random

So I am currently learning C, and I have some confusion about how the `random()` function works.
I know I have to provide a seed, but I don't know how to actually generate the random number.

```
srandom(seed);
long int value= random(40);
```

When I try this it gives me a compiler error:

```
too many arguments to function ‘long int random()
```

The end goal is to get a random number between 1 and 40.
I should add that the goal is to not use the `rand()` function.

Comment: random doesn't take arguments; you passed the value 40.

Comment: Please do not place `srand()` before each call to `rand()`. Call it once at the start of the program. I do not know why you renamed those library functions. What are they? How can we know what they do? Are they non-standard functions or your own?

Comment: Read the POSIX specification for [`random()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/random.html) — it tells you a lot of what to do.  For the rest, read [Is this C implementation of Fisher-Yates shuffle correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3348142) to see how to generate an unbiassed random number in the range 0..N (for 1..40, you'll use a random number in the range 0..39 and add 1).

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your question is precisely answered by the compiler.
You are passing **'40'** to the function **random()** which it is **not** supposed to receive.

The signature for random() is:

```
long int random (void)
```

**void** keyword here is indicator that the function in hand is not supposed to receive anything.

Here's an example program to generate 6 random numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    int max = 5; 
    for (int c = 0; c <= max; c++){
      num = random();
      printf("%d\n",num);         
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
fire-trail@Sahai-Yantra:~$ gcc try.c 
fire-trail@Sahai-Yantra:~$ ./a.out
1804289383
846930886
1681692777
1714636915
1957747793
424238335
```

To reach your end goal of generating random numbers within a given range using `random()`, see [How to generate a random number from within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range).

Comment: So far, so good.  Now he wants to generate a number in the range 1..40; how do you go about doing that?

Comment: Already answered here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range

Comment: OK; so update your answer to reference the question, or include an outline of the information and the cross-reference to its source.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is this okay? Or should I add up anything? newbie here.

Comment: I recommend using the link's title rather than an uninformative 'follow this link'.  The latter looks like spam, even though it isn't.  I've updated as I suggest.  I might avoid using the bold for 'end goal' and I'd probably use back-ticks around `random()` so it appears in constant-width font, but those are second-order refinements.

Comment: I guess I'm not supposed to comment this but noted and thanks!

Comment: `random()` is not a standard function. it is a posix extension.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is right there in the error thrown by the compiler

> too many arguments to function ‘long int random()

Change random(40) to random()

Answer (score 2):

There is no argument in `random()` function.

See [man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random) page of random(). Prototype of random()

```
long int random(void);
```