# Strange behaviour of rand() in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, random, srand

While using Apple Xcode, the C program I include below will always return a 5 for y but z will return a random number, even though they have the same expression. Can you identify a reason for this behaviour?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    x = ((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    y=((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX)*10);
    z=((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX)*10);
    printf("Time %d\n", x);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number y %d\n", y);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number z %d\n", z);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is because the value from `time` (the seed value) is increasing slowly, and is divided by a large number, so the quotient won't be any different until some longer time has elapsed. The second call to `rand` produces a value altogether diferent from the seed.

Comment: This seems to be restricted to Xcode and Mac OS X, since I don't have this problem when running in Linux. Is that so? And in Xcode if I use srandom and random() it works identically in both cases. Are random() and srandom different from the srand and rand()?

Comment: I am getting similar result from MSVC but `7` instead of `5`. I expect the `7` to go up to `8` eventually.

Comment: I receive the `5` on OS X / XCode, too.

Comment: The man pages for rand (`man 3 rand`) say that the rand interface is obsolete and should be replaced with arc4random(3) (e.g., got to terminal and type `man 3 arc4random` to get the documentation).

Comment: Perhaps it depends on the implementation of `rand`, which might compute a new value and return it, or return the current value after computing the next value. In the latter, the seed value will be returned on the first call to `rand`. P.S. in my test the `7` has now advanced to `8`.

Comment: You call `time()` twice;  there is a potential for it to change between the two calls.  If `x` is intended to hold the value used as the seed, better to assign `x`, then use x as the seed.

Comment: this statement: `x = ((unsigned int)time(NULL));` is assigning a 'unsigned int' to a 'int'.  The implicit conversion feature of C may save you (but the compiler will output a warning message.)

Comment: on a 32 bit architecture, this expression: `(double)(RAND_MAX)*10)` is trying to multiply `2147483647` (the max positive signed int) by 10.  This will result in a signed number overflow.   Multiplying a double by a integer results in a implicit conversion being performed by the compiler.  This will cause the compiler to output a warning message.  Also, assigning a `int` from a `double` will cause the compiler to output a warning message.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 2):

**`rand-31`**

Here's an adaptation of your program which shows more detail of what's going on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = ((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    srand((unsigned int)x);
    int r1 = rand();
    int y  = ((double)r1/(double)(RAND_MAX)*10);
    int r2 = rand();
    int z  = ((double)r2/(double)(RAND_MAX)*10);
    printf("Time %d\n", x);
    printf("Random 1: %d\n", r1);
    printf("Number y: %d\n", y);
    printf("Random 2: %d\n", r2);
    printf("Number z: %d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

It captures the result of the two `rand()` calls independently of the calculation so that they can be printed.  It also ensures that the value passed to `time()` is the same as the value printed, though the chances of them being different are pretty small.

When I ran it a few times, I got the outputs:

```
Time 1508694677
Random 1: 1292016210
Number y: 6
Random 2: 1709286653
Number z: 7

Time 1508694685
Random 1: 1292150666
Number y: 6
Random 2: 1821604998
Number z: 8

Time 1508694701
Random 1: 1292419578
Number y: 6
Random 2: 2046241688
Number z: 9

Time 1508694841
Random 1: 1294772558
Number y: 6
Random 2: 790587255
Number z: 3
```

As you can see, the values returned by `rand()` are different, but not very different, and consequently the computed value isn't all that different.

**`rand-23`**

One easy upgrade option is to use the [`drand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) functions, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = ((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    srand48((unsigned int)x);
    int r1 = lrand48();
    int y  = ((double)r1/(double)(RAND_MAX)*10);
    int r2 = lrand48();
    int z  = ((double)r2/(double)(RAND_MAX)*10);
    printf("RAND_MAX: %d\n", RAND_MAX);
    printf("Time:     %d\n", x);
    printf("Random 1: %d\n", r1);
    printf("Number y: %d\n", y);
    printf("Random 2: %d\n", r2);
    printf("Number z: %d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

The code prints `RAND_MAX` mainly to show that it is compatible with the range of values returned by `lrand48()`, which is documented to return a value in the range 0..2<sup>31</sup>-1.

This gives different and arguably better results:

```
RAND_MAX: 2147483647
Time:     1508695069
Random 1: 705270938
Number y: 3
Random 2: 1758232243
Number z: 8

RAND_MAX: 2147483647
Time:     1508695074
Random 1: 1465504939
Number y: 6
Random 2: 733780153
Number z: 3

RAND_MAX: 2147483647
Time:     1508695080
Random 1: 1948289010
Number y: 9
Random 2: 1222424564
Number z: 5
```

**`rand-13`**

Alternatively, you can do what the macOS documentation says and switch to [`arc4random()`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html).  The link is to 'legacy' XCode 5 documentation, but the functionality hasn't changed recently.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = ((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int r1 = arc4random_uniform(INT_MAX);
    int y  = ((double)r1/(double)(RAND_MAX)*10);
    int r2 = arc4random_uniform(INT_MAX);
    int z  = ((double)r2/(double)(RAND_MAX)*10);
    printf("INT_MAX:  %d\n", INT_MAX);
    printf("RAND_MAX: %d\n", RAND_MAX);
    printf("Time:     %d\n", x);
    printf("Random 1: %d\n", r1);
    printf("Number y: %d\n", y);
    printf("Random 2: %d\n", r2);
    printf("Number z: %d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

This uses `arc4random_uniform()` to generate a value in the range 0..INT_MAX, the same range as the other functions generated.  There is no analogue to `srand()` with the `arc4random()` family of functions.

Sample runs:

```
INT_MAX:  2147483647
RAND_MAX: 2147483647
Time:     1508695894
Random 1: 938614006
Number y: 4
Random 2: 851262647
Number z: 3

INT_MAX:  2147483647
RAND_MAX: 2147483647
Time:     1508695900
Random 1: 1332829945
Number y: 6
Random 2: 386007903
Number z: 1

INT_MAX:  2147483647
RAND_MAX: 2147483647
Time:     1508695913
Random 1: 1953583540
Number y: 9
Random 2: 1273643162
Number z: 5
```

**`rand-83`**

Note that if you want a random integer between 0 and 10, then you should use `arc4random_uniform(10)` directly and not do the computations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = ((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int y = arc4random_uniform(10);
    int z = arc4random_uniform(10);
    printf("Time:     %d\n", x);
    printf("Number y: %d\n", y);
    printf("Number z: %d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Example outputs:

```
Time:     1508696162
Number y: 5
Number z: 3

Time:     1508696163
Number y: 7
Number z: 5

Time:     1508696165
Number y: 3
Number z: 8
```

One further advantage of `arc4random()` et al is shown when I managed to run the program 3 times in a single second.  With the other generators, these would have produced the same results because of using the same seed.

```
$ rand-83;rand-83;rand-83
Time:     1508696213
Number y: 4
Number z: 0
Time:     1508696213
Number y: 0
Number z: 1
Time:     1508696213
Number y: 9
Number z: 6
$

$ rand-31;rand-31;rand-31
Time 1508696334
Random 1: 1319865409
Number y: 6
Random 2: 1619339200
Number z: 7
Time 1508696334
Random 1: 1319865409
Number y: 6
Random 2: 1619339200
Number z: 7
Time 1508696334
Random 1: 1319865409
Number y: 6
Random 2: 1619339200
Number z: 7
$
```

JFTR: Code compiled on a MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.  I used GCC 7.2.0 (rather than XCode 9) to compile, but the system library — and it is the library that is critical here.

Comment: I see this is a Mac GCC related issue (I'm also using a MacBook Pro with High Sierra 10.13, but with Xcode 9.1 beta), the problem is that I have to develop to the widest compatibility possible, since my teacher uses a Linux system and he uses rand() and srand with no issues.

Comment: There’s no guarantee about what quality of random number you get from the `rand()` function.  There’s limited guarantees about the range of values returned from the `rand()` function. Portable code can’t expect the same results on different machines using the `rand()` function.  The only problem is with expectations, and/or the algorithm used to derive a value in the range 0..10 (or 0..9).  There are other, better ways to do that.

Comment: Note the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348142) by [Roland Illig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225757/roland-illig) to the question [Is this C implementation of the Fisher-Yates shuffle correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343797) which shows how to generate a number in the range 0..N-1 accurately without bias.

Answer (score 0):

You have just learned an important lesson:

**Do not use `time(NULL)` to seed your random number generator.**

Yes, I know "everyone does that". That doesn't make it correct. (In fact, "everyone" doesn't do that, although it is very common in example code. It is very uncommon -- and even in the uncommon cases incorrect -- in code which actually requires random numbers for production purposes.)

The fact is, "time in seconds since epoch" is a very unrandom number. It takes a full year for the first six bits to change; for almost a day, only the low-order 16 bits change, and for a second -- which is enough time to start thousands of processes -- it doesn't change at all. Since you are guaranteed to be able to get the same random sequence if you use the same seed, it should be obvious that you need to work a bit harder to ensure that you have a more random seed.

So what to do? Most operating systems these days have some mechanism to generate a truly random number (or a number which is as close to be random as the laws of physics will allow). On many Unix and Unix-like systems -- including Mac OS X and Linux -- you can get a very good unsigned 32-bit random number by reading four bytes from `/dev/random`. That's too expensive to do for every random number you will need, but it's excellent as a seed:

```
uint32_t seed = 0;
FILE* rf = fopen("/dev/random", "r");
if (rf != NULL) {
  if (fread(seed, sizeof seed, 1, rf) != 1) seed = 0;
  fclose(rf);
}
if (!seed) { /* Fallback to some other mechanism */ }
srand(seed);
```

Independent of seeding, `rand` is often not a very good random number generator, particularly on implementations where `RAND_MAX` is 32767. But no random-number generator, no matter how good it is, can compensate for the lack of a good seeding strategy.

(Some libraries will seed automatically, but there is a good reason why manual seeding is part of the interface: you may need to rerun the same random number sequence. For example, if you are using a PRNG to generate random test data and some run of your test program triggers a bug, you will want to rerun the program using the same random number sequence to verify that the bug has been fixed. One simple strategy is to use a command-line flag to supply an explicit random number seed, and ensure that the test harness always prints the random number seed which gave rise to the results.)

Comment: it's better to read `/dev/urandom`, although modern Linux also maps `/dev/random` to `/dev/urandom` anyway

Comment: @phuclv: my understanding is that Linux hasn't yet managed to [unify `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Random-Unification-Future), although that's apparently still the plan. On macOS, which is actually the context for this question, the two are indeed the same device. So I guess it makes little difference except on systems where it makes a difference. :-)

Comment: indeed, although [they're already pretty much the same](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-5.6-Random-Rework)

Comment: @phuclv: I read that too, but the link I chose is more recent. Anyway, that's really not the point of this answer/diatribe, which I honestly think needs to be repeated more.

Answer (score 0):

after removing the (unneeded) clutter from your program, the following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. eliminates unneeded local variables
3. performs the desired functionality.
4. clearly exposes what is actually happening with the `time()` and `rand()` functions.
5. documents why each header file is included

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf()
#include <time.h>   // time()
#include <stdlib.h> // srand(), rand()

int main( void )
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    printf("Time %u\n\n", (unsigned int)time(NULL) );

    printf("first call to rand:  %d\n\n", rand());

    printf("second call to rand: %d\n\n", rand());

    return 0;
}
```

a typical run of the proposed code produces outputs similar to the following:

```
Time 1508783846

first call to rand:  1113266715

second call to rand: 810898123
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to identify the problem and it is related to the use of Xcode 9.1 beta, which for some reason broke srand and rand(). After reverting back to Xcode 9.0.1, everything is working fine again.