# rand() behaves differently between macOS and Linux

Tags: c, random

I'm trying to generate a random-number sequence with rand().
I have something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int Random(int min, int max)
{
  /* returns a random integer in [min, max] */

  double uniform; // random variable from uniform distribution of [0, 1]
  int ret; // return value
  srand((unsigned int)clock());

  uniform = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
  ret = (int)(uniform * (double)(max - min)) + min;

  return ret;
}


int main(void)
{
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("%d ", Random(0, 100));
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

It made different results when executed on [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave) and [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver).

It works on Ubuntu:

```
76 42 13 49 85 7 43 28 15 1
```

But not on macOS:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Why doesn't it work well on macOS? Is there something different in random number generators?

Comment: You must call srand() only once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877089/strange-behaviour-of-rand-in-xcode

Comment: Also, `clock()` is often a count from the start of program execution. It is more usual to pass `time()` to `srand()`. The C18 standard says of `clock()` ***7.27.2.1** implementation’s best approximation to the processor time used by the program since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related  only to the program invocation.*

Comment: I think that the `clock()` function behaves strangely on macos, can you display its value each time you use it?

Comment: see [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/995714). And `rand()` on mac is so shitty that you should use `arc4random()` on it instead, see [Why does rand() % 7 always return 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7866754/995714), [Rand() % 14 only generates the values 6 or 13](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20263187/995714)

Comment: In addition to the other comments, it's likely that your Mac implementation is running much faster than your ubuntu implementation. Perhaps you are running ubuntu in a VM on your Mac?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Mac user. To generate random numbers I initialise the seed like this:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Plus, try initialising it in your main.

Answer (score 2):

If reproducible "random" numbers are something you care about, you should avoid the `rand` function. The C standard doesn't specify exactly what the sequence produced by `rand` is, even if the seed is given via `srand`. Notably:

- `rand` uses an unspecified random number algorithm, and that algorithm can differ between C implementations, [including versions of the same standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098148/difference-in-output-of-srand-on-windows-gcc-and-expected-output-for-c-program).
- `rand` returns values no greater than `RAND_MAX`, and `RAND_MAX` can differ between C implementations.

Instead, you should use an implementation of a pseudorandom number generator with a known algorithm, and you should also rely on your own way to transform pseudorandom numbers from that algorithm into the numbers you desire. (For many ways to do so, see [my page on sampling algorithms](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#For_Floating_Point_Number_Formats). Note that there are [other things to consider](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Ensuring_Reproducibility) when reproducibility is important.)

See also the following:

- [Does Python have a function to mimic the sequence of C's rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331996/does-Python-have-a-function-to-mimic-the-sequence-of-cs-rand)
- [Why is the use of rand() considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad/52881465#52881465)
- [How predictable is the result of rand() between individual systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600866/how-predictable-is-the-result-of-rand-between-individual-systems/59604864#59604864)

Answer (score 0):

`rand` is obsolete in Mac. Use random() instead.

Comment: Can you explain why (by editing your answer)? Why would it be different between Linux and Mac? Isn't it the same (e.g., GCC) under the covers (not a rhetorical question)? Even if it is obsolete, why would `rand` give a non-random sequence of numbers?

Comment: random() and srandom() to initialise the random seed.

Answer (score 0):

On macOs, use `srandom()` and `random()` instead of `srand()` and `rand()`.