# How to stop duplicates values in an array in C

Tags: c

I am creating a 5x5 board game in C. The problem I am having is that when I use the rand() it duplicates some of the numbers. How do I stop the duplicates and 0's?

Sorry if too basic a question. I'm new to C.

```
int createboard() {

  int rows;
  int columns;
  int board[5][5];
  int board2[5][5];

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++) {
    for (columns = 0; columns < 5; columns++) {
      randomNumber = rand() % 25;
      board[rows][columns] = randomNumber;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My question is why you thought to use `rand()`. You clearly don't want random *numbers*; you want a random **order** of a specific set of numbers, which is a very different thing, so generating random numbers isn't the answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3343797/2410359

Comment: You have to keep a track of numbers that are already generated. Run a while loop around the rand function, and bail out of it when the new unique number is taken. That is a simplest way. This could be helped with an additional array containing 25 Boolean values corresponding to the status of the random number (already generated = true, new number = false). I have to post it here so @Quicky can see it. Otherwise it is down-voted.

Comment: rand is a standard C function and it may be used for generating random numbers.  More about the quality of this function is here: https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/141644-finding-distribution-rand-function.html

Comment: @VladP: You ought to put answers in the answers section, where they can be peer-reviewed which perhaps includes a downvote. Don't take downvotes personally, I don't, and at the time of my writing, my answer below has a downvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rand()` would not be a particularly good generator if the probability of drawing the same number twice was zero.

A standard approach here would be to generate the `board` with consecutive numbers, then *shuffle* it by swapping elements at random a certain number of times.

A good shuffling algorithm is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Good solution, perhaps a bit of overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Use srand() function instead of rand function.
rand() will give same numbers  after each program.
Refer this for help. This is for improvement of your program this is not answer
[Rand() vs srand() function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rand-and-srand-in-ccpp/)

Answer (score 0):

Deleted since downvoted. That is a reason why it is removed.

Comment: but this is just a clumsy way to work around the inherent limitations of using the wrong design.

Comment: One problem with this approach is that you are assuming that a `rand` implementation draws numbers in its periodic cycle such that when the results are transformed under the function `% 25`, they completely fill the range [0, 24]. The C standard makes no such guarantees (a trivial counterexample would be a `rand` implementation that draws only even numbers), so this approach *could* cause an infinite loop. Granted, this is unlikely but it does illustrate an important flaw in this technique.

Comment: @Bathsheba: While it is not formally stated in the C standard, I am confident the intent of the standard is that `rand` is intended to select from the integers in [0, RAND_MAX] with uniform distribution. A `rand` that returned only even values (always, not just in some limited subsequence) would be defective.