# Problem with rand%100 for random number generation in C

Tags: c

So I have a homework assignment, and we need to generate random numbers between 1 and 100 in C. I have a working example with int i = rand()%100.

But according to the homework that is technically incorrect which I don't really get. The Homework explanation is as follows

"1.1   We use a random number generator to simulate bus arrival times. ===> the rand( ) function.The rand( ) function returns a pseudo random number 0 to RAND_MAX (2^31-1 in linux).To generate a random number, rn, between 0.0 and 1.0;    rn = rand( ) / RAND_MAX.(by the way, a lot of people do below to create, say, 2 digit random numbers.         r_num = rand( ) % 100;    since % 100 is 0 to 99. However, this is wrong. The right way of generate 2 digit random number is:    divide 0-RAND_MAX in 10 intervals and see where the random number falls.         The interval time is, it = RAND_MAX / 100.         Then, map it to one of 0 - 99 by the following:       0          1         2          3           .........                   99       0          it       2*it      3*it                                  99*it to RAND_MAX    If the rand( ) returns a number  is between (12*it) and (13*it), the 2 digit random number is 12.)"

I was hoping someone could take a stab at explaining what it is saying, I'm not really looking for code examples just an understanding of the problem.

Comment: The interval method actually has the same problem that the % method does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of problems there, both having to do with how the modulo operator works.  `a % b` effectively gives you the remainder when you divide a by b.  So let's suppose that we're computing numbers modulo 4.  Let's also assume that RAND_MAX = 6, because I really don't want to have 32768+ rows in my table.

```
  a | a % 4
------------
  0 | 0
  1 | 1
  2 | 2
  3 | 3
  4 | 0
  5 | 1
  6 | 2
```

So if you're using your approach to generate random numbers between 1 and 4, you have two problems. First, the simple one: you're generating numbers between 0 and 3, not 1 and 4.  The result of the modulo operator will always be between 0 and the modulus.

The other problem is more subtle.  If RAND_MAX doesn't divide evenly into the modulus, you won't get the same probability of each number.  In the case of our example, there are 2 ways each to make 0 through 2, but only one way to make 3.  So 3 will occur ~14.3% of the time, and each other number will occur ~28.6% of the time.  To get a uniform distribution, you need to find a way to deal with cases where RAND_MAX doesn't divide evenly.

Answer (score 2):

`RAND_MAX` is usually `2^31 - 1` so it is equal `2147483647`.

But let's assume for simplicity that we have a very strange system, with `RAND_MAX` = 100 (so `rand()` can return `0` to `100`, that's 101 numbers). And let's assume the `rand()` function has ideal [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)).

Now, what is the probability of `rand() % 100` ? The numbers `1` to `99` have the same probability, that is `1/101`. But `0` has the probability `2/101` because when `rand()` return `0` and when `rand()` return `100`, the expression `rand() % 100` will be equal to `0`. So `0` can come more often then any other numbers, actually two times more often. So our distribution of 2-digit numbers with `rand() % 100` is not uniform.

Now, the text proposes a solution to the problem. The proposed solution is to split `0` to `RAND_MAX` region into 100 even parts, so that numbers within each part have the same probability. Then roll `rand()` and see in which region the number ended. If `RAND_MAX` is `2147483647` and we for example get a number `279172968` we can see it ends in the 13th region - between `RAND_MAX / 100 * 13 = 279172868` and `RAND_MAX / 100 * 14 = 300647704`.

The solution is also flawed, as we can see, that it is impossible to divide `0` to `RAND_MAX` into 100 even parts when `RAND_MAX % 100` is not equal to `0`.

I feel the only viable solution is to discard all numbers greater then `RAND_MAX / 100 * 100` (using C integer arithmetic). The rest of the numbers will have uniform distribution and the maximum will be divisible by 100, so with the rest we can just `rand() % 100`. So something like this:

```
int get_2_digit_number() {
      int r = 0;
      while (1) {
          r = rand();
          if (r > (RAND_MAX / 100 * 100)) { 
              continue;
          }
          break;
      }
      return r % 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find relevant code on SO.  For example, the `rand_int()` code below is based on code for integers in an answer to
[Is this C implementation of the Fisher-Yates shuffle correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3343797) (and specifically the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348142) by [Roland Illig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225757/roland-illig)):

```
static size_t rand_int(size_t n)
{
    size_t limit = RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX % n;
    size_t rnd;

    while ((rnd = rand()) >= limit)
        ;
    return rnd % n;
}
```

The idea is that you calculate and ignore the large values returned by `rand()` which would lead to biassed results.  When one of the large values is returned, you ignore it and try the next value.  This will seldom need more than two calls to `rand()`.

You might find some of the external references in [Shuffle array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127503/shuffle-array-in-c) useful too.